# Order of constraint and differentiation (Optimization on Constraint)

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, constraints

I need to find the maximum and the minimum of
$$f(x,y)=x^2-y-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
on $G$: $x^2+y^2=1$.
My problem lies in the order in which i perform differentiation and imposing constraint:

- Differentiation + constraint:
  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x-\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\rightarrow
     \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}_G=2x-2x=0.$$
- Constraint + differentiation:

$$f(x,y)_G=x^2-y-2\rightarrow\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}_G=2x.$$

Can anyone please explain to me why is that and which is the correct path to follow?

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: Yes, either use Lagrange multipliers or parametrize the unit circle, letting $x=\cos t$ and $y=\sin t$ and differentiate with respect to $t$.

Comment: Note that the problem is equivalent to extremising $x^2-y-2$ subject to $x^2+y^2 =1$, which may be more approachable.